# Encountered fatal error executing joborg.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-batch

While executing

```
private static final String CURRENT_VERSION_JOB_EXECUTION = "SELECT VERSION FROM %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?";
```

by spring (it is already written in JdbcJobExecutionDao) i am gettting this error

```
Encountered fatal error executing joborg.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

it is not able to get record from **batch_job_execution** table but record is present in table.
my app is running on kubernetes and i m getting this error from kubernetes but not from my local code.

Comment: How are you querying for the Job information?

Comment: The result doesn't lie, the application doesn't see it, so it isn't there. Maybe it isn't using the database you think it is using.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla i am not querying ir is already written in spring

Comment: @M.Deinum i have not changed anything and running code from my local machine so it is woking. it was working fine and i have not deployed new build

Comment: The error isn't lying, so the software isn't getting a result. That is simply a fact. Now either it is querying for something that isn't there (and you are looking at the wrong data) or it uses a different database/schema/... then you are looking in. Either way the starting point is that the error isn't lying.

Comment: @M.Deinum i agree with you but fact is it was working now i m geiing error

Comment: So something changed, maybe deliberate, maybe not. But something is different.

Comment: No i have not changed anything even i have not deployed new build

Comment: Now i restarted my service and working fine but still doesn't get why it happened

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/EmptyResultDataAccessException.html)

> Data access exception thrown when a result was expected to have at
>   least one row (or element) but zero rows (or elements) were actually
>   returned.

You can approach this in few ways:

1. Modify your query to always return 1 result.
2. Catch the exception and apply a behavior that you find fit. For example you can check [this guide](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/queryforobject-throws-emptyresultdataaccessexception-when-record-not-found/) and use it as an example.
3. Use [`query method`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) instead to avoid this exception.

Please let me know if that helped.